# Transition to a black screen

Tags: java, android

I believe I have my code set up correctly but when I try to debug it, after it transitions from the splash screen it just goes right to a black screen. I know I imported the layout correctly but it still goes black.

This is the code for the splash screen

```
package com.example.equate.jones;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class EJ_Splash extends Activity {

    protected boolean _active = true;
    protected int _splashTime = 3000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ej__splash);

        // thread for displaying the SplashScreen
        Thread splashTread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                        synchronized(this){
                            wait(4000);
                        }

                    }
                 catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    // do nothing
                } {

                    finish();

                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EJ_Board.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        };
        splashTread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_ej__splash, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

This is the code for the screen it is supposed to transition to.

```
package com.example.equate.jones;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class EJ_Board extends Activity {

    private ImageView button1;
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.warm);

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ej_board);


        button1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        { 
            public void onClick(View view) 
            { 

                mp.start(); 
            }
        });
    }

}
```

This is the xml for EJ_Board

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your XML code for the EJ_Board?

Comment: I'm a little confused why you have a menu inflater on your splash screen. Your splash screen should just transition to your next page without any menu. I don't think that has anything to do with your problem, but regardless, still something to think about. :)

Comment: Alright, I'm pretty new to android programming but I know a decent amount of java. Not too familiar with XML so that's why I was hoping it was with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is with the ImageView. You need to add an image to your drawable folder, then change your `android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"` to the name of the image you saved. This will give you the image you need for your button. Hope that helps

Edit:

For your splash screen, try something like this:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity  {
   private long splashDelay = 5000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
        {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                finish();
                Intent homeIntent = new Intent().setClass(SplashActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(homeIntent);

            }

        };

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(task, splashDelay);

    }
}
```

Then in your home activity you can set your menu:

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.locationButton:
                Intent locationIntent = new Intent(this, LocationActivity.class);
                startActivity(locationIntent);
                return true;
            case R.id.diningButton:
                Intent diningIntent = new Intent(this, DiningActivity.class);
                startActivity(diningIntent);
                return true;

            case R.id.topXXVButton:
                Intent topIntent = new Intent(this, DiningActivity.class);
                startActivity(topIntent);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Try this:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity  {
   private long splashDelay = 5000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
        {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                finish();
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(EJ_Splash.this, EJ_Board.class);
                startActivity(mainIntent);

            }

        };

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(task, splashDelay);

    }
}
```

Comment: There isn't anythign wrong with the transition, I think its starting the activity wrong

Comment: Did you add the activity to your Android manifest? Post your Android manifest if you would please.

Comment: I added some code that might help you. Let me know if it works for you.